# CSS label:before with content styling not working unless id provided for elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have built a clickable am / pm button that is part of a time selector. It will be sitting inside a dynamic table (html table where the user can click a button to add rows to the table). Since it is in a dynamic table, I will be generating the elements and won't have much use of element id's when trying to access them in javascript (as I won't know them individually).

With the below clickable label, is there any way to achieve the same result without assigning an id to the checkbox?

```css
.text_toggle
{
    display: none;
}

.text_toggle + label
{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #aaa;
}

.text_toggle + label:hover
{
    color: blue;
}

.text_toggle:not(:checked) + label:before
{
    content: attr(data-off);
    position: absolute;
}

.text_toggle:checked + label:before
{
    content: attr(data-on);
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<input id="am_pm" class="text_toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
                <label for="am_pm" data-off="am" data-on="pm"></label>
```

Comment: Doesn't your demo do that already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make a label and put your checkbox inside it, then you add another element with your custom attributes.

```css
.switch{
/* other styles here */
}
.switch > input[type=checkbox]{
display:none;
}

.switch input[type=checkbox] + span::before{
  content: attr(data-off)
}
.switch input[type=checkbox]:checked + span::before{
content: attr(data-on)
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" />
<span data-off="Off" data-on="On"></span> <!-- I made it with span, but feel free to use any other tag -->
</label>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Why does it work when you stick it inside a label?

Comment: By default, input inside a label is asigned to parent. Is like if you assigned "for" attribute to the "input" element inside. :D